# Finding out if its a leap year and setting accordingly

Tags: python, django, django-forms, leap-year

I have a form that has an initial `end_date`.  I am having a Value error because this year is a leap year and we are currently in February.

My code has a end day of 30 but I am having trouble figuring out how to write the code that will discover if its a leap year and set the initial `end_date` to the correct last day of february.

Here is my forms.py that controls the end_date initial value

```
class MaturityLetterSetupForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from datetime import datetime
    today = datetime.today()
    start_year = today.year
    start_month = today.month
    start_date = datetime(start_year, start_month, 1)
    try:
        end_date = datetime(start_year, start_month, 30)
    except ValueError:
        end_date = datetime(start_year, start_month, ?)

    super(MaturityLetterSetupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['start_date'] = forms.DateField(initial=start_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y"),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker', 'value': today }))

    self.fields['end_date'] = forms.DateField(initial=end_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y"),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker', 'value': today }))
```

**EDIT**
After speaking to @Paul
my init became:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from datetime import datetime
    import calendar
    today = datetime.today()
    start_year = today.year
    start_month = today.month
    start_date = datetime(start_year, start_month, 1)
    if calendar.isleap(start_year) and today.month == 2:
        end_date = datetime(start_year, start_month, calendar.mdays[today.month]+1)
    else:
        end_date = datetime(start_year, start_month, calendar.mdays[today.month])
    super(MaturityLetterSetupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['start_date'] = forms.DateField(initial=start_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y"),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker', 'value': today }))

    self.fields['end_date'] = forms.DateField(initial=end_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y"),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker', 'value': today }))
```

Which finds the last day of the current month.

Comment: bear with me as I get sidetracked- Seeing your `if leapyear and if feb` statement made me think about if all conditions in boolean logic are evaluated. We'll they aren't ([short-circuit](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)). As it is now, 12 months out out every 48 would be a leapyear and the comparison will have to look up the month value 12 times. But if you flip the order (month then leapyear) only 4 times out of 48 it'll be feb, and then it'll have to lookup the leap year value. haha. this optimization(?) brought to you by Friday afternoon

Comment: I like learning new, random things haha. it's probably really not important in this example. I really doubt attributes on a datetime object are very costly. But- it seems good to keep that in mind if one part of the comparison involves a database query or some other heavier operation that would be nice to skip. thank _you_ for prompting me to research something! haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about [calendar.isleap(year)](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html) ?

Also, don't use try/except to handle this but an `if` conditional. Something like:

```
if calendar.isleap(year):
    do_stuff
else:
   do_other_stuff
```

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I will accept as soon as it allows me to and I will update the code for people to see the solution

Comment: I like this answer but why is using try not a good way to handle this?

Comment: I found a better solution I believe.  I have updated my code, is the solution I posted, the best?

Comment: @Lostsoul: A development rule-of-thumb: Don't use exceptions to control program flow. Use exceptions to handle exceptional conditions. IMO leap years are not that exceptional. You also incur unnecessary overhead by simply wrapping code in exception handler.

Comment: @Steve: At first glance that seems ok but, correct me if i'm wrong, but leap years are adjusted in February which has 29 days in leap years instead of 28... Why is 30 coming up as an issue? Which month are you evaluating when that happens?

Comment: @PaulSasik The error of `day out of range` comes up when I am trying to evaluate February.

Comment: @Steve: Take a closer look at your logic. As I mentioned in an earlier comment, February has 29 days in leap years, not 30. It has 28 days in non-leap years.

Comment: @PaulSasik Okay I see now that mdays is giving me 28 days not 29 for the month of February.  So now I need to figure out how to add the extra day for February during leap years

Comment: @PaulSasik check my updated code, please.  See if I finally got it haha

Comment: @Steve: Your edit looks good. Take my feedback with a grain of salt though. I don't have Python set up on my current machine... Just make sure your months are 1-based and not 0-based. That's a PITA issue in Java, I don't recall Python.

Comment: @PaulSasik Thanks so much.  You were a great help to me

Comment: @PaulSasik Thank you, I'm learning so its good to know.  I'll take your advice for my own code as well.  Have a nice day!